# status: request denied when i am trying to find nearby data using place api

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I am creating an android app: I am trying to show all the nearest gas stations.
But I can't get any data.

I used a JSON method for requesting place data and use both keys Android key & Browser key, but I can't get any data.

I tried google for a step by step tutorial.
https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search

I am used following link with API key for get search data
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?location=48.859294,2.347589&radius=5000&types=food|cafe&sensor=false&keyword=vegetarian&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere

Please, anyone help me with this.

Comment: How about showing us what you've done so far?

Comment: I am edited refer link and search link that i used.